# How to add audio at specific time on video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to add audio on new created video.
In this, i have want to add the on specific time duration using ffmpeg.

Comment: Already answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/708125/add-audio-at-specific-time-in-video-using-ffmpeg). TLDR; need to add `-async 1`

Answer (score 4):

```
ffmpeg -y video.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:30 -i music.ogg -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -shortest out.mp4
```

The `-itsoffset` option here means 30 seconds from start.

Comment: how to do in vice versa, i mean add video to specific time in video

Comment: I think answerer left out an -i. Try this: `ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:30 -i music.ogg -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -shortest out.mp4`